# Default 2D pose estimate when navigating

Tags: ros, navigation, pose, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to set a default 2D pose estimate when navigating using amcl?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9516/default-2d-pose-estimate-when-navigating/) by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 995 on 2011-03-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can set an intial pose either with the "initial_pose_x, initial_pose_y, initial_pose_z" parameters or through the "initialpose" topic. [You can find more info on these on the AMCL page.](http://www.ros.org/wiki/amcl)

---

Originally posted by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) with karma: 1033 on 2011-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1